# $lookup do not work with field starting with a $

Tags: mongodb

```
b.getCollection('actions').aggregate([
      { $lookup : {
           from: "companies",
           localField: "company.$id",
           foreignField: "companies:_id",
           as: "companyId"
           }
      }
])
```

Error message : `fieldpath field names cannot start with $`.

I cannot rename the field, it's a production site, and if I cannot do a simple JOIN I'm going back to SQL.

```
b.getCollection('actions').aggregate([
     { $lookup : {
           from: "companies",
           localField: "company.$id",
           foreignField: "companies:_id",
           as: "companyId"
            }
     }
])
```

Comment: mongoDb does not allow to insert fields that start with '$'

Comment: I Inherited this schema : so yes it is possible , maybe I should migrate  and rename ? "company" : {
        "$ref" : "companies",
        "$id" : ObjectId("55438646d4c64aa2a9d84902")
    },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DBrefs** will have fields starting with **'$'**, so direclty we cannot use 
**$lookup** on DBrefs.

using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), $lookup can be used 
( $objectToArray is supported from **version 3.4.4** and above)

```
db.getCollection('actions').aggregate([
{
     $project: 
     {
       companiesArray: { $objectToArray: "$company" }
     }
},
{
     $unwind: "$companiesArray"
},
{
     $match:  {"companiesArray.k" :"$id"}
},

{ $lookup : {
       from: "companies",
       localField: "companiesArray.v",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "companyId"
       }
}
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Sir, I will try right away

Comment: nice hack, is there also some cleaner way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax errors in your "JOINT", it should look like this

```
b.getCollection('actions').aggregate([
     {
        $lookup : {
           from: "companies",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "companies._id",
           as: "companyId"
          }
     }
])
```

- I'm assuming thats how your schema looks, cant really know unless you share it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'm trying your solution soon

Comment: not working, and it seems the problem comes from the DB: below I have copy an exemple of a lot of records looking like this with a $id and $ref "company" : {
        "$ref" : "companies",
        "$id" : ObjectId("55438646d4c64aa2a9d84902")
    },